# jain sip API not able to send notify to endpoints at same machine

Tags: java, spring, sip, jain-sip

I am trying to send SIP notify to a SIP Endpoint but Getting error if SIP Endpoint is at the same machine. If i use two different machines it works.

```
sipCoreComponentService.sendCheckSyncNotify(to, destination,destPort, false);
```

the this function has :

```
        ClientTransaction trans= sipLayer.sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(notifyRequest);
        trans.sendRequest(); // Send it out-of-dialog
        trans.setApplicationData(this);
```

What could be the problem?

I am getting this error:

```
 Exception javax.sip.SipException: Cannot assign requested address: Datagram send failed
 gov.nist.javax.sip.stack.SIPClientTransaction.sendRequest(SIPClientTransaction.java:972)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when the target address is an invalid IP such as using broadcast/multicast address as destination in an unicast transaction. Can you paste the whole exception and what is the SIP message that you build (key being request URI and Route/Via headers), if you are using private DNS, what does the dest DNS name resolve to?